# Simple PHP form not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

I´m trying to make a form that works. I´m using codeigniter, the view has this form:

```
    <form class="renuncia_form" action="/formulario/send_form" method="post">
        <p>
            <label for="nombre">Nombre y apellidos:</label>
                <input name="nombre" type="text" id="renuncia_nombre">
            <br>
            <label for="participe">Nº Partícipe: </label>
                <input name="participe" type="text" id="renuncia_participe">
            <br>
            <label for="nombre_fondo">Nombre del Fondo de Inversión o SICAV: </label>
                <input name="nombre_fondo" type="text" id="renuncia_fondo">
            <br>
            <label for="email">Direccion de correo electrónico: </label>
                <input name="email" type="text" id="renuncia_email">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="renuncia_submit" name="enviar">
        </p>
     </form>
```

And the controller has this php:

```
public function send_form(){
    if($_POST['submit'] == "Submit")
    {
        $errorMessage = "";

        if(empty($_POST['nombre']))
        {
            $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your name</li>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['participe']))
        {
            $errorMessage .= "<li></li>";
        }

        $varMovie = $_POST['nombre'];
        $varName = $_POST['participe'];

        if(empty($errorMessage)) 
        {
            $fs = fopen("mydata.csv","a");
            fwrite($fs,$varName . ", " . $varMovie . "\n");
            fclose($fs);

            header("Location: thankyou.html");
            exit;
        }
    }

}
```

I don´t know if I´m doing correctly the form. I just want to work it as a normal form action, that you click on submit an it takes you to a new page saying "Thanks for your email", no AJAX, just that.

Can anybody help me out with this one?

**Edit:** Also where do I put the recipient e-mail?

Comment: You should be using **isset()**

Comment: If you are using codeigniter, you maybe want to use the form helper library.

Comment: Um...where is your "name='submit'" in your form.  If you don't have an element named "submit" your very first if() won't work at all...neither will most of the isset() examples below.  However, use isset() as they describe, but AFTER you name your submit button. [edit] - look at @Nwafor's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if($_POST['submit'] == "Submit")
```

should be

```
 if(isset($_POST['enviar']))
```

As submit button is not having `name` as `submit`, instead it is `name='enviar'`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if(isset($_POST["enviar"]) && $_POST["enviar"] == "Enviar")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are translating your form anyway you used

```
if($_POST['submit'] == "Submit")
```

and you used in form

```
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="renuncia_submit" name="enviar">
```

your actual submit button name is `enviar` and not `submit`. Since this is a button I would reccomend to check `isset()`

```
if(isset($_POST['enviar']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got

```
if($_POST['submit'] == "Submit")
```

and then everything else if the condition is satisfied. It is never as there isn't such field. Just remove it and it'll be fine.

As for mail, you should access it via `$_POST['email']`. If you want to send an email, take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) or [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/mail).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but the problem is the action attribute.

why don't use From helper to create this form?. Anyway if you don't what or can't use it change the action to something like `http://localhost/your_project/index.php/formulario/send_form`.

read about base_url here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Besides if($_POST['submit'] == "Submit") is wrong. It must be

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['submit'] === "Enviar"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['enviar']))
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
public function send_form(){

    if(array_key_exists('submit',$_POST))
    {
        $errorMessage = "";

        if(empty($_POST['nombre']))
        {
            $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your name</li>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['participe']))
        {
            $errorMessage .= "<li></li>";
        }

        $varMovie = $_POST['nombre'];
        $varName = $_POST['participe'];

        if(empty($errorMessage)) 
        {
            $fs = fopen("mydata.csv","a");
            fwrite($fs,$varName . ", " . $varMovie . "\n");
            fclose($fs);

            header("Location: thankyou.html");
            exit;
        }
    }

}
```